# Add a newline to a String if not empty in Java

Tags: java, strings, comparative-review

This should be really simple. I'm searching for the cleanest & shortest way to add a newline to a non-null String if it is not empty, i.e. `myString.isEmpty()` is `true`. I know of a number of ways to do this, but none of them are as elegant as I would like them to.

For context, the string I'm working on will essentially be a list of key-value pairs that is filled with a loop. Every key-value-pair needs to have a newline appended after it, though not if it is the last one. An example for the end value of `myString` might be the following:

```
Boss : Julia
Worker : Louis
Intern : Tom
```

I could do

```
myString += myString.isEmpty() ? "" : "\n";
```

but is this really the **best** way to do this?

I also thought of

```
if(!myString.isEmpty()) myString += "\n";
```

Which way would be preferable, and why?
Are there better alternatives?

Comment: Try [Apache StringUtils.defaultIfBlank](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#defaultIfBlank(T,%20T)). This may not be the most efficient approach and it requires another library but it is very clear from the code what is being done.

Answer (score 5):

> Every key-value-pair needs to have a newline appended after it, though not if it is the last one.

So are you interested to know how to concatenate `String`s together using `\n` as a delimiter, or are you still interested to know how can you append `\n` to a non-empty `String`? Both have different implementations...

(using Java 8 where applicable below)

**`\n` as a delimiter:**

```
String toString = organizationMap.entrySet().stream()
                    .map(ThisClass::constructStringFromEntry)
                    .filter(v -> !v.isEmpty())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

**`\n` as an optional suffix:**

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = organizationMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Entry<String, String> entry = iterator.next();
    // some other processing...
    // time to append the current entry to builder
    String entryString = constructStringFromEntry(entry);
    builder.append(entryString);
    if (!entryString.isEmpty() && iterator.hasNext()) {
        builder.append('\n');
    }
}
String toString = builder.toString();
```

I am suggesting the usage of a `StringBuilder` here since the kind of `String` concatenation in a loop is usually structured, hence it can be better done relying on that rather than `+`. Usually, I will prefer the enhanced `for`-loop over using an explicit `Iterator`, but its usage here is required in order to avoid adding the last `\n`.

Comment: I'm interested in both of these, but simply concatenating the strings with streams seems more elegant than the solution I currently have. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I fear there isn't much to improve. You could avoid the concatenation if the String is empty :

```
myString = myString.isEmpty() ? myString : myString + '\n';
```

Comment: The problem I see with this solution is having to write `myString` four times - which is OK for myString, but not that nice-looking for `reallyReallyReallyComplicatedAndLongStringName`. Performance-wise, this would of course be better, but performance should not be an issue here. Thank you nontheless!

Comment: Put the line in a method.  Then you only have to write reallyReallyReallyComplicatedAndLongStringName once.

Answer (score 2):

From the performance points of view, it would be better to use second sample. Cause of in the first sample JVM creates two String objects for "" and "\n" (it depends on compiler also) and make two operation of concatination in the both cases.

Would be better to use StringBuilder or StringBuffer instead String object, cause of "+" will create new String object from myString and "\n" through StringBuffer.append() and in append method you cat put char or byte primitives instead of String object.

```
if (stringBuilder.length() == 0) stringBuilder.append('\n');
```

Comment: Since Java 6, unless particular cases (in loops for instance), using a StringBuilder should not change a lot since the compiler transforms automatically strings concatenations into StringBuilder calls. Eg: `String one = "1"; String two = "2"; String three = one + two;` into `String three = new StringBuilder().append(one).append(two).toString();`.

Comment: You are right, but in our case it will be translates to someone like this.
`myString = new StringBuilder().append(myString).append(myString.isEmpty() ? new String("") : new String("\n")).toString();`

it will allocate two new String object and create default length arrays and for the StringBuilder also and adds some operations for GC.

Comment: @Luke35 (Sorry, I can't add comments to non-my answers) from the Java Code Convention and readable sources it would be better to use `if` construction.
`if (builder.lenght() == 0) {
    builder.append('\n');
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is a common pattern - only apply the separator if both parts are substantial.

```
public static String join(String a, String j, String b) {
    if (a == null) {
        // No a - just becomes b.
        return b;
    }
    if (b == null) {
        // No b - just becomes a.
        return a;
    }
    if (a.length() == 0) {
        // No a - just becomes b.
        return b;
    }
    if (b.length() == 0) {
        // No b - just becomes a.
        return a;
    }
    return a + j + b;
}

public void test() {
    System.out.println(join(null, ",", "Hello"));
    System.out.println(join("Hello", ",", "Hello"));
    String s = "";
    for (String append : new String[]{"Hello", "a", "", "", null, "", "b"}) {
        s = join(s, ",", append);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Attempting to do a complicated thing with a one-liner is doomed.